# Why is brakeman-guard raising "NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard, brakeman

I'm using the following gems in a Rails 5.2 app.

```
# /Gemfile

group :development do

  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-spring'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'brakeman', require: false
  gem 'guard-brakeman'

  # ...

end

# ...
```

Brakeman was working fine with Guard, but recently something has changed.

```
> bundle exec guard 

... usual startup trace 

------ brakeman warnings --------
00:52:13 - INFO - 6 brakeman findings
00:52:13 - ERROR - Guard::Brakeman failed to achieve its <start>, exception was:
> [#8fe733251410] NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for #<Brakeman::FilePath:0x00007f8d0f2c9ea0>
> [#8fe733251410] /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@myapp/gems/guard-brakeman-0.8.3/lib/guard/brakeman.rb:206:in `decorate_warning'

...

00:52:13 - INFO - Guard::Brakeman has just been fired
```

Looking at the [gem repo](https://github.com/guard/guard-brakeman/blob/master/lib/guard/brakeman.rb), there is a comment near the line raising this error

```
/lib/guard/brakeman.rb
# ...
# line 206
output << " near line #{warning.line}" if warning.line
if warning.file
  # fix this ish or wait for brakeman to be fixed
  filename = warning.file.gsub(@options[:app_path], '')
  # ...
```

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Have I configured my app incorrectly and this is preventing Brakeman working with Guard? Or is there an issue in the gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's raising that error because the latest version of Brakeman (4.5.1) changed the class of `warning.file` from a `String` to a `Brakeman::FilePath`.

`guard-brakeman` really should have been using `Brakeman::Warning#relative_path` all along, but unfortunately [it was (wrongly) removed in Brakeman 4.5.1](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/pull/1354).

In short, please try pinning to Brakeman 4.5.0 for now and wait for either the next Brakeman or guard-brakeman release to address this issue.

I have opened https://github.com/guard/guard-brakeman/pull/36 and https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/pull/1365.

Issues like this should probably be reported as bugs to the projects instead of being asked on StackOverflow.

***Update: guard-brakeman 0.8.4 fixes this issue.***

Comment: Thanks @justin, I was not sure whether the bug was with the gem or my implementation. Thanks for clarifying